# Which linux distro is most proactive in fixing bugs?

Tags: linux, bugs

On which secure and stable Linux distro am I **least** likely to come across minor bugs which have been open for a year or more?

Comment: The technically accurate but useless answer is the distro with the fewest users, since it’s least likely to have bugs filed in the first place ;-).

Comment: What makes a Linux distribution _secure_ (and stable) is a matter of opinion, as it differs depending on your requirements and expectations.

Comment: @Kusalananda I would defer the concept of stability and security to the maintainers of the distro. For example Debian states that security patches are applied to the stable release before being applied to the testing realease. Therefore testing has worse security, despite having the "freshest" software (hence least likely to suffer from non-critical bugs).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Normally a distro which contains the most up-to-date packages is the most bug-free which means you could choose from Fedora, Gentoo and Arch Linux. Then even the three of these distros have maintainers for packages, so in the end it depends on maintainers' eagerness to keep their packages up to date. Lastly Gentoo is in the league of its own as you can freely compile/install the latest and greatest packages without waiting for a maintainer to do his job. In terms of user-friendliness, Fedora is the best, Arch is in the middle, Gentoo is meant for geeks. Then there's LFS but I don't consider it to be a distro.

All other distros prefer to use "stable" version of packages and patch them (after receiving bug reports from users) which could be quite slow.

Lastly the most recent packages may contain new not yet reported bugs but generally there are more fixes than bugs.

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer my question.